# Add partition to unallocated partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I'm trying to extend my unallocated partition to my far right Ubuntu partition.
I can't move /dev/sda5 to the left. I need to merge the two together somehow.

[image]

Comment: Would be very helpful to provide the current partition configuration, and what you want the destination to be.

Answer (score 1):

In the screencap /dev/sda5 has a key next to it. The key icon beside a partition means that said partition is mounted and thus cannot be modified. Running GParted from a live (cd/usb) session should allow you to make the changes you need.

Comment: So should I unmount the partition on live usb? Wouldn't that delete all my files?

Comment: If you are running on live usb none of your disks would be mounted. You are having problems because your trying to make changes to a disk that is mounted. The screenshot shows that it is your root partition, so you will need to use liveusb since you can't just unmount the root partition and then use GParted.

Answer (score 0):

Live USB is the correct choice here. It will allow you to make changes in the root partition of your installation without any hassle.